# I need help debugging a basic C program to calculate Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c, loops, infinite-loop, fibonacci

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(); 
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    c= 2;
    for ()
    {
        a = c + b;
        printf(a,"\n");
        b = c + a;
        printf(b,"\n");
        c = a + b;
        printf(c,"\n");
    }
}
```

I am a beginner at C and am trying to write a program to list the Fibonacci sequence.

This is what I have so far. I know I have at least two issues, one being the for loop. How would I make it an infinite loop?

My second issue that I'm running into is this error message

```
"prog.c:3:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {
 ^"
```

If someone could help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: `for ()` -> `while(true)` might fix both your issues.

Comment: Also `int main();` --> `int main()`

Comment: @frslm `while(1)` in c. `true` is only supported in c++ (unless using stdbool.h)

Comment: When I make these changes, it still doesn't work, and instead displays a long list of errors...

Comment: I think syntax for "for" here is "for(;;)"

Comment: your `printf` invocations are wrong.

Comment: use `printf("%d\n",a);` . also your loop become infinite

Comment: An infinite loop here will eventually crash because you go over max int.  You probably want to test all three of those vars for being over half of max int and break the loop when they are.  You also should use unsigned ints, or maybe even unsigned long ints (and again, test for going over half of them).

Comment: The `int` type can't handle an infinite range of Fibonacci numbers. A 32-bit `int` will break before the 50th term.

Comment: **You really ought to get more diagnostics than that *one* line.** If not, then you should get a new compiler.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has multiple elementary bugs. Suggest starting simpler and read some book/reference instead of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` after `int main()` -- should take care of the compiler error

`while(1)` instead of `for()` -- will run an infinite loop

Comment: That is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you might do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
    unsigned int c;
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        if (c < b)
            break;
        printf("%u\n",c);
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b;
    }
}
```

Modified to use unsigned int and change comparison based on comment.

Bobby

Comment: Signed integer overflow is not well defined. it would work if the variables are `unsigned int` apart from `< 0` which should be less than the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for Fibonacci series

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int var_z;
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a);
        printf("%d\n",b);
        a = a+b;
        b = a+b;
    }
}
```

Eg. https://eval.in/1013468

Answer (score 0):

/* Fibonacci series */

#include

int main()

{

```
long int a =0;

 long int b=1;

 long int c=1;

  int n,d=1;


   printf(" Enter the number of 

   terms ");

   scanf("%d",&n);

   do

     {


       printf("%d\n",c);

              c=b+a;

              a=b;

              b=c;

              d=d+1;


       }

            while(n>=d);

             return 0;


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How to read this particular compiler error:

> prog.c:3:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token { ^

This is telling you that the error occurs on line 3:

```
1: #include <stdio.h>
2: int main();
3: {           // <------ compiler is complaining about this line
```

and that it's seeing a `{` where it shouldn't.  The only time it should see a `{` is after a function declarator (function name plus argument list) or after an identifier (for a struct, union, or enum definition).

The problem is that you shouldn't have the semicolon after `int main`  Because of it, the compiler is treating `int main()` as a *declaration*, not the beginning of a function *definition*.

Remove that semicolon and the error will go away.

Important lesson here - the compiler doesn't tell you where you actually made the error, but where that error *prevents it from translating the code*.  If you have a deeply nested loop, like

```
for (...)
{
  for (...)
  {
    for (...)
    {
```

and you forget to put in the closing brace on the innermost loop, the compiler won't say "you forgot to put a closing brace *on this innermost loop*"; instead, it will complain about a line some ways down, either because it's reached the end of the program or the next function definition without seeing the closing `}` of the previous function.

> How would I make it an infinite loop?

The syntax for an infinite loop is either `while(1)` or `for(;;)`.  Doesn't matter which you use, the compiler should (*should*) generate the same code for both.  Like other people have said, though, Fibonacci numbers get very large very quickly, too large for a native integer data type to represent.  You'll start seeing overflow errors after computing the 50th F number or so.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors with your code, the semi colon after main is wrong, your algorithm dont output fib sequence and the for loop it is typed incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()  //;<-- doesn't contain semicolon
{
    /* use a better variable name for clarity
    int a; --> a
    int b; --> last number
    int c; --> sum
    a = 1;
    b = 0;
    */
    int a = 1;
    int last = 0;
    int sum;

    for (;;) // infite for loop needs 2 semicolons to work
    {
        printf("fib : %d\n", last);
        sum = a + last;
        last = a;
        a = sum;
    }
}
```

By the way, you should limit your for loop or else it going to overflow your int variable. long unsigned a,sum,last would give you more bits to store.